# Find maximum number in a string list with a specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer, max

Using Python 3, I have a list of the form

```
ls = ["a", "b_0", "b_1", "b_2", "c", "d_0", "d_1"]
```

I have to find out the maximum number after "b_". In this case, the desired output is 2.

I came up with something like that:

```
import re
p = re.compile("b_(\d+)")
nums = [int(p.match(l).group(1)) for l in ls if p.match(l) is not None]
res_max = max(nums)
```

But I don't like the repetition of `p.match` two times.

What is the most pythonic way of achieving this?

The maximum number after `d_` is not guaranteed to be less than the maximum number after `b_`

I specifically need to find out the maximum number after the "b_" prefix. I am not interested in the maximum number after any other prefixes

Comment: Most Pythonic way might be without using any modules or imports.

Comment: How about the first element in the list `"a"`? Or do you mean to just ignore anything that has no `"b_"` in the prefix?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano ignore anything that has no `b_` as a prefix

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
>>> max(int(i.split("_")[-1]) for i in ls if i.startswith("b_"))
2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like repetition, you can use walrus operator `:=`

```py
import re

ls = ["a", "b_0", "b_1", "b_2", "c", "d_0", "d_1"]

p = re.compile(r"b_(\d+)")

max_num = max(int(m[1]) for l in ls if (m := p.match(l)))
print(max_num)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
>>> max([int(i.split('_')[-1]) for i in ls if i.split('_')[-1].isdigit()])
2
>>>
```

Comment: I think you also need `and i[0]=="b"`

Comment: @not_speshal It doesn't need to be I gues.

Comment: The number in `d` is not guaranteed to be less than the number in `b`

Comment: @robertspierre Yeap! that's what my code does :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> max([int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in ls if i.split('_')[0] == 'b'])
2
```

Comment: I'm agree with you but I prefer use  `'_'` as delimiter because I guess `a, b, c, d` are just example. I can use `startswith`

Answer (score 1):

In such case, expand the list comprehension into explicit list appending:

```
import re
p = re.compile("b_(\d+)")

nums = []
for l in ls:
    m = p.match(l)
    if m is not None:
        nums.append(int(m.group(1))

res_max = max(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension-

```
ls = ["a", "b_0", "b_1", "b_2", "c", "d_0", "d_1"]

res = max([int(string.split('_')[1]) for string in ls if string.startswith('b_')])

print(res) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This could another way

```
ls = ["a", "b_0", "b_1", "b_2", "c", "d_0", "d_1"]
res_max = max([int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in ls if i[0] == 'b'])
print(res_max)
```

**Output: 2**

Answer (score 0):

One way would be nested comprehensions:

```
import re
p = re.compile("b_(\d+)")
nums = [
    int(m.group(1))
    for m in (p.match(l) for l in ls)
    if m is not None
]
res_max = max(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way of doing it using `re.search()`

```
    import re

    ls = ["a", "b_0", "b_1", "b_2", "c", "d_0", "d_1"]
    pattern = r'b_(\d+)'

    lst = [res.group(1) for i in ls if (res := re.search(pattern, i))]
    print(max(lst))
```

Output:

```
    2
```

In the 6th line it's checking every element in the list `ls` if it matches the `pattern`, then adds the first group of the matching string (which is the number) to the list `lst`.

The part `res := re.search(pattern, i)` is assigning the value of `re.search(pattern, i)` to the variable `res` and at the same time as its checking if it's `None` then the `if` statement won't activate, if it has a value then the `if` statement will get activated. This is thanks to the 'Walrus Operator' `:=`.